# log4net custom appender not working

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

i have create a custom appender using log4net for my project. i created the SampleLogAppender class using AppenderSkeleton interface.

```
namespace Sample.Integrations.Utilities {

public class SampleLogAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    public static IContext Context { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (Context != null)
        {
            Context.LogMessage(RenderLoggingEvent( loggingEvent ));
        }
    }


    protected override bool RequiresLayout
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

}

if i configure this class in config  file, it is not working. below configuration i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,   log4net" />
     </configSections>

   <log4net>
     <appender name="LogAppender" type="Sample.Integrations.Utilities.SampleLogAppender ">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="[%date{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}] [%-5level] [%class]-[%method] - [%message] %newline" />
         </layout>
      </appender>
       <logger name="LogRoot">
         <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
      </logger>
  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

above config file i am using, but it is not working. below i am using the log4net configuration.

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(ConfigLocation));

         Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("LogRoot");
```

i am having Logger class also.

```
 public class Logger
{

    public static ILog Log;

    public static string ConfigLocation = string.Empty;

    private static readonly string ConversionPattern = "[%date{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}] [%-5level] [%class]-[%method] - [%message] %newline";



    public static void ConfigureLog(IContext context)
    {

        SampleLogAppender .Context = context;

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(ConfigLocation));

        Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("LogRoot");
    } }
```

i initialize Logger like below in startup project.

```
Logger.ConfigureLog(_context);
```

i use the logger like below.

```
Logger.Log.Debug("Test");
```

when i call this , the Append() method doesn't call.

please give some solutions.

Comment: It looks like you spelled "appender" wrong under the <log4net> element.

Comment: please explayn what "does not work" mean.

Comment: Append method in SampleLogAppender class does not call anymore.

Comment: Where are you setting the `Context` property?

Comment: @stuartd, i have edited question. please provide me some solution.

Comment: Logger.ConfigureLog(_context); in the startup project. context property is static. so i use SampleLogAppender.Context=context;

Comment: I think you may have to call [`ActivateOptions()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.ActivateOptions.html) on the appender as you're modifying it at runtime.

Comment: @stuartd, i use log4net for addin project. in that project , it is not working. but i use log4net to some exe project, on that project it is working. i don't know y this is happening.

Comment: Are you using the same code in both projects?

Comment: yes. i am using same code in both project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43837/discussion-between-ram-nivas-and-stuartd)

Comment: You can try to enable log4net's internal debug programmatically. You need to set the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging property to true. Obviously the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced. This may show you if there is an error inside Log4Net.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried working with your configuration file and after a few fixes it worked, see the log4net section:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogAppender" type="Sample.Integrations.Utilities.SampleLogAppender">
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="[%date{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}] [%-5level] [%class]-[%method] -                      [%message] %newline" />
   </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Something strange that was in your code and didn't work was a space in the type, in the end before the quotation mark.

```
<appender name="LogAppender" type="Sample.Integrations.Utilities.SampleLogAppender ">
```